# Knowing the status of my question under reopen queue

Tags: support, vote-to-reopen

Is it possible to check the status of my question which is under hold, and has been edited just now for reopening queue?

this is my [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18931891/how-to-speed-up-my-jscrollpane)

Comment: I haven't looked to see what questions they are, but I can see that at the current time there are two questions in the reopen review queue and that your question has one reopen vote.

Comment: Your question was already bumped into the queue [16 hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2974044). Apparently further edits after that do not keep re-bumping it into the queue.

Comment: @animuson but reopening has 4 days time

Comment: @CreatedC by 4 days time, if you mean that a question will be switched from "on-hold" to "closed" after 5 days, then that is true, but even when that happens, the post can be reopened at that time.

Comment: Might make a nice feature request, so an editor knows if they've no done enough or the review is still ongoing when their question remains closed (reviewer names redacted if needs be)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Diamond moderators have the ability to find the reviews that a question is/has undergone - see [this newsletter](http://modnewsletter.stackexchange.com/2013/02/january-2013-newsletter/). Also, 10k users have the ability to see all review history - so as a 10k'er, you could trudge through the reopen review history looking for your post.

As you are neither, the only way for you to find this is to ask a mod, or just see whether your question gets reopened. On Stack Overflow, the reopen queue is often processed very quickly - almost always less than a day.